# Avoid the historian records - Hyperledger Composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to avoid the historian records? I don't want to store the transactions information, for example, information about the participant who invokes the chaincode.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to stop writing historian records.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think I'm going to work directly on Fabric, because Composer has a couple of limitations on what I want to do.